# Subversion: how to nuke a repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

Is there a way to **completely** erase a Subversion repository so that users can't access to old revisions?

PS: I have root access on the repositories machine.

Comment: Is there anything you want to keep in this repository? Or is it just a case of starting again from scratch?

Comment: I don't need to keep the old data, I just want a new repository without actually recreating a new one.

Comment: It really is easier to create a new repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the root folder of the repository, but saving the `conf/` folder it has inside. Then, create a new repository with `svnadmin create`, and overwrite the old configuration folder on it.

EDIT (for completeness): as Tunnuz and Jim T have pointed out, you may want to save also the contents of the `hooks/` folder if it contains custom scripts.

Comment: This would lose any active hooks in the hooks directory.  I think this advice, extended to also save the hooks directory, is what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, if you want to keep the configuration, MOVE all the contents of the repository directory to a safe place, then use svnadmin to create a new blank repository, then copy your conf and hook directories back in so that the users and automation scripts are replaced.

Your repository will then be blank, starting again from revision 1.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the folder on the HDD? Subversion repositories are stored in folders...
Alternatively you can change the configuration to deny all access to everyone (the method will vary depending on how the authorization is configured).

Comment: The Subversion repositories have a complex structure, they aren't just a folder. Which one should I remove? How do I know that I won't corrupt the repository configurations? In other words: is there a command to accomplish that?

Comment: They ARE a folder... There is a root folder which holds all your repos and under it you have a subfolder for each repository, in example you can delete C:\Subversion\repos\{name} and the {name} repo will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Delete folder manually (each repository has it own folder)

2.) or use [svnadmin](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re31.html) command (svnadmin dump).

Comment: svnadmin dump — Dump the contents of filesystem to stdout.